# How to allow an user to modify any system settings in Domain with Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, domain-controller, remote-desktop-services

I created a domain with windows server 2012.

I logged in with an user account.

And with default, this account cant access to Remote Desktop setting, LAN setting, ... and any system settings.

I don't know how to allow an specify setting, this case, I want to allow this user can modify Remote Desktop setting, and LAN setting.

Tks all.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Domain Controller. Open

> Active Directory Users and Computers

. Select your user -> **Properties** -> tab **Member Of** -> Add 
-> Type in *Enterprise Admins* -> Check Names -> OK |OK

Comment: If the user has the right to edit the Domain Admins group, and he was not a member of it (or Enterprise Admins) - this is a PROBLEM.

Comment: But in case I just want this user just can modify 1 setting as Remote Desktop setting. How to do that ? Thank you.

Comment: Ya, I just want to specify setting, not all setting like Enterprise Admins

Comment: I would just add the user account to the Domain Admins group, seeing as OP does not have an AD forest.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure a server a domain controller role, you had to do it as a user with administrative rights. This user should now be a member of the Domain Admins group and can modify Remote Desktop setting, LAN setting and many others. Automatically!

UPD. Policy "Prohibit access to properties of a LAN connection" [described in technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc975891.aspx). It has no relation to the delegation of the right to configure the network.

Comment: It's not my case, I dont want to new Admin account, I just want an normal user just can modify the Remote Desktop setting, but I dont know how to do this, maybe in User Configuration in GPO.

Comment: In order to get the rights to a domain or a domain controller (which is equivalent) - requires an account with domain administrator privileges (or enterprise administrator). No another way.

Comment: I think it's the "Prohibit access to properties of a LAN connection" GPO, but it cant apply. I dont know why.

Comment: If you are logged on a domain controller under the ordinary user - 
dismiss the domain administrator, he does not deserve his position.

Comment: What about admin agree ordinary user cant modify 1 setting in his computer ?

Comment: In this case, I have concerns about his mental abilities. Especially if we talk about the network domain controller settings.

Comment: So ADDS have nothing to do this case ? so what "Prohibit access to properties of a LAN connection" GPO can do ?

Comment: No way - ADDS designed not idiots.

Comment: So can you explain what "Prohibit access to properties of a LAN connection" GPO can do. Thank you

Comment: This policy supersedes policies that remove or disable parts of the Local Area Connection Properties dialog box, such as those that hide tabs, remove the check boxes for enabling or disabling components, or disable the Properties button for components that a connection uses. If you enable this policy, the system ignores the policies that disable parts of the Local Area Connection Properties dialog box.

Comment: Can you have any reference about this ? I think this is so difficult to understand